# Image splitter by analysis

Tags: photos, scanning, splitter

I want to scan old photos to the computer, and to make the process faster I want to scan a few photos together each time, and then split them up later on.

I scanned three photos together, but now I can't find a splitter that will perform the requested task.

I'm looking for a splitter that will split by the edges of the photos (or at least I would give the application a certain colour or pattern to use).

Does anyone know of such an application?

Comment: not a specific pre-defined grid.
Just row/column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP photosmart essentials did the job for me.